# numpy array <=> python DB-API adapter?

Tags: python, sqlite, numpy, adapter

Anyone knows is there any other adapter between numpy array and sqlite database besides the atpy?

Thanks!

Rgs,

KC

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the default package, `sqlite3`?

```
In [1]: import sqlite3

In [3]: conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

In [4]: cur = conn.cursor()

In [5]: cur.execute('select * from table1')
Out[5]: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xa3142c0>

In [6]: scipy.array(cur.fetchall())
Out[6]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```

Comment: i know this is kinda old now but a quick question, isnt this gonna double create items in memory like discard the python array and add a new numpy array, isnt there any way to oneshot this